# Filling remaining width and height around centered div

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to fill the remaining screen space around a `div` that is centered on the screen like so:

[image]

The red `div` has the following properties as I would like to keep the same aspect ratio and have it in the center of the screen:

```
position: absolute;
height: 80%;
width: auto;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Is it possible to adjust the 4 surrounding divs dynamically to fill the remaining space on the screen?

EDIT: The red `div` is a transparent image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree a lot with the [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48047126/8620333) as the question was to fill remaining spaces and the answer simply provided equal rows and in the second row equal columns. So it's clear that the 4 surrounding divs are not filling the remaining space.

I think this is what you need:

1. Solution with 2 surrounding divs and pseudo element *(use fixed height/width for the image or simply keep the original size)*:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
}

.middle:before,
.middle:after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}

img {
 opacity:0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"> </div>

<div class="middle">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/">
</div>

<div class="bottom"> </div>
```

2. Solution with 4 surrounding divs *(use fixed height/width for the image or simply keep the original size)*:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
}

.right,
.left{
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}

img {
 opacity:0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"> </div>

<div class="middle">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/">
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div class="bottom"> </div>
```

3. Solution without surrounding divs where you can set **% height**:

```css
body {
   /* 100vw = the width of the screen*/
   /* 200 = initial width of the image*/
   /* 100 = initial height of the image*/
   /* 40vh = the % we specified in the image (40%) but used with vh unit */
  --main-start: calc((100vw - ((200 / 100) * 40vh)) / 2);
  --main-end: calc(var(--main-start) + ((200 / 100) * 40vh));
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,green var(--main-start),transparent var(--main-start),transparent var(--main-end),green var(--main-end));
}

body:before,
body:after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
  background:blue;
  width:100%;
}

img {
  height: 40%;
  opacity:0.6;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/">
```

4. Solution without surrounding divs where you can set **% width**:

```css
body {
   /* 100vh = the height of the screen*/
   /* 200 = initial width of the image*/
   /* 100 = initial height of the image*/
   /* 40vw = the % we specified in the image (40%) but used with vw unit */
  --main-start: calc((100vh - ((100 / 200) * 40vw)) / 2);
  --main-end: calc(var(--main-start) + ((100 / 200) * 40vw));
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image:linear-gradient(green var(--main-start),transparent var(--main-start),transparent var(--main-end),green var(--main-end));
}

body:before,
body:after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
  background:blue;
  height:100%;
}

img {
  width: 40%;
  opacity:0.6;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/">
```

**UPDATE**

Since the OP will use transparent image and want the colored background to stay, I added in the 2 last solutions linear-background to create a transparent gap below the image since i didn't use any other elements.

Comment: I need to set the image height to a specific value

Comment: @SidneydeVries yes you can set the height of image like you want, have a try ;) something you cannot do with the other solution though

Comment: @SidneydeVries as you can see i used fixed height/width image, so simply replace with any image you want and it will take the necessary space ... and in the third solution you can use % to specify height/width

Comment: @SidneydeVries i also provided a 4th way where you can adjust width also, so you have 4 different ways and all of them will keep the image in the center while you can specify width/height as you need and keep ratio

Comment: I am trying to use Solution 3 as it fits my use case the most. However the image is transparent so the green background on the body makes it not work

Comment: @SidneydeVries you can remove this background ;) i simply use it as illustration ... or did you need it ? if yes i can adjust it ;)

Comment: Yeah i need the image to be in the center and to be surrounded by the backgrounds. Thanks for your time

Comment: @SidneydeVries ok let me adjust then :) 1 min

Comment: @SidneydeVries updated, it wasn't easy as expected .. but i found a solution using linear-gradient to create the tranparent part, but i used some calculation to find start and end points. So let me know if there is something not clear ;)

Comment: It seems to be working. Thanks! Crazy that we have to use such a complex solution. I hope its supported on most major browsers

Comment: @SidneydeVries gradient and variable are well supported so you shouldn't face a lot of issue with them ;)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">

    </div>
    <div class="box">
      HERE !
    </div>
    <div class="box">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">

  </div>
</div>
```

How about using `display: flex`?

You can make responsive layout easily.